Overflow not showing when I used position fixed in tailwind css
this is my code I also added overflow-y-auto but still not working
import React from 'react';

const Footer = () => {
   return (
        <footer className="bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-700 w-full fixed bottom-0 overflow-y-auto">
         <div className="mx-auto w-full max-w-screen-xl">
              {/* footer content */}
         </div>
      </footer>
    );
}

export default Footer;


the element with overflow-y-auto should have a set height in order for it to be able to overflow, otherwise its height will just increase as you add content to it.
For instance, if you know your footer should be 80px tall, and the content is more than 80px tall, you'll see the scrollbar appear.
If you can visually represent what you'd like it to look like and what it currently looks like it would help giving you a better answer
